# Using d3.sort() to put items in array at front of dataset

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, d3.js

I have a dataset where I'd like to put items contained in an array to the front of the dataset.

So I'm trying:

```
climate.sort(function(a, b) {

    if (dotscountries.indexOf(a.country) > -1) {
        return b - a
    } 
 });
```

This isn't working.

My data looks like the following (csv):

```
date,country,value1,value2,dataset,region,global
1991,France,6.702,0.239,intensity,eu,392.7922
1991,California,12.5,0.305,intensity,na,350.9
1991,Italy,7.343,0.282,intensity,eu,416.44257
1991,Japan,8.603,0.272,intensity,asia,1066.42158
1991,Brazil,1.617,0.407,intensity,sa,245.68986
1991,South Korea,6.226,0.656,intensity,asia,269.85239
1991,Germany,11.614,0.398,intensity,eu,928.95023
```

How can I put items in an array to the front of the dataset?

Comment: What does your data look like? How is it not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option, I think, is instead to *filter* the items in that array out of the dataset, then *concatenate* them to the front of it.

For example:

```
var removed = [];
climate = climate.filter(function(a) {
    if(dotscountries.indexOf(a.country) > -1) {
        removed.push(a);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});
// if you actually want climate sorted, then sort it now
climate.sort(cmp); removed.sort(cmp);
climate = removed.concat(climate);
```

This will sort the two pieces independently, and put the elements in `dotcountries` at the front of the array.

Comment: Ok this approach makes sense. I ended up needing to put at the end, so I used a forEach and push.